# FreeBSD 12.2 i386 libs on an amd64 System

Tags: freebsd

I installed FreeBSD 12.2 on my server with an amd64 kernel. I tried to compile my source which was created for an i386 system. And I get this error:

> skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/gcc9/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd12.3/9.5.0/../../../libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++

I thought its beacuse I need the shared i386 lib libaries and I was searching how to install them. Just have found to install it over "bsdinstall" which doesnt work on my root or to unpack a .tgz file which isnt in my system either.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "I tried to compile my source" that sounds like programming to me.

Answer (score 2):

1.You have to check if your package (`lang/gcc9`) was compiled with the option `multilib=ON` using `pkg info gcc9` and see in the `Options` section. If not, you have to do this from the ports tree `/usr/ports/lang/gcc9` :

```
$ sudo make config
(set 'Multilib' option to ON)
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install clean
```

or as root (one shot, as you wish ...):

```
# make config install clean
```

FYI, FreeBSD has 32bits support by default, see `/usr/lib32` and do not forget to check if you include this directory when building your project.

Some infos:

- on the package : [FreshPorts - lang/gcc9](https://www.freshports.org/lang/gcc9/)
- How to Install Applications: [Chapter 4 - Installing Applications Packages and Ports](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/ports/)

Plz Check/read these docs before proceeding.

2.If you have installed/compiled `gcc9` with `multilib` option set to `ON`, troubles come from your environment (IDE, missing paths from the compiler options, etc...).

**EDIT**: just checking my own compiler, I forgot to mention `gcc/g++` could report whether it was compiled with multilib support or not, using the preproc builtins information (see `--enable-multilib` below), you could use the following eg:

```
$ g++ -m32 -E -P -v -dD 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: x86_64-portbld-freebsd13.0
Configured with: /wrkdirs/usr/ports/lang/gcc11/work/gcc-11.3.0/configure --enable-multilib --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-noplugin --disable-nls --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --libdir=/usr/local/lib/gcc11 --libexecdir=/usr/local/libexec/gcc11 --program-suffix=11 --with-as=/usr/local/bin/as --with-gmp=/usr/local --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/local/lib/gcc11/include/c++/ --with-ld=/usr/local/bin/ld --with-pkgversion='FreeBSD Ports Collection' --with-system-zlib --without-zstd --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,jit --prefix=/usr/local --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/local/man --infodir=/usr/local/share/info/gcc11 --build=x86_64-portbld-freebsd13.0
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.3.0 (FreeBSD Ports Collection)
```